# Combinatorics - Parking Function

Tags: combinatorics

Elbert and Yaiza each draw 10 cards from a 20-card deck with cards numbered 1, 2, 3, . . . , 20. Then,starting with the player with the card numbered 1, the players take turns placing down the lowest numbered card from their hand that is greater than every card previously placed. When a player cannot place a card, they lose and the game ends.
Given that Yaiza lost and 5 cards were placed in total, compute the number of ways the cards could
have been initially distributed. (The order of cards in a player’s hand does not matter.)

Assume five cards when the game ends of the 20 includes 1 and four other cards to create a set $\alpha = ${$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$} of **rank ordered cards**. The problem could be solved by invoking parking function of size 5

A parking function of size is a sequence $( a_1 , … , a_n )$ of positive integers such that if $b_1 ≤ b_2 ≤ ⋯ ≤ b_n$is the increasing rearrangement of $a_1 , … , a_n$, then $b_i ≤ i$.

The number of parking functions is well-known to be $(n+1)^{(n-1)}=(5+1)^{(5-1)}=6^4=1296$
For any five cards satisfying the parking function condition are equally likely that the elements of $\alpha$ is chosen from 1,2,... , 20 and the fraction of times such five numbers form alpha is $\frac{5}{20}$

Thus the number of ways that the cards are originally distributed $= 1296.\frac{1}{4} = 324$ Let me know if this is correct? I doubt i am right, but atleast I tried a different approach.

The original solution is posted here in this link.  https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2023/feb/comb/solutions.pdf

Comment: What is your reasoning for thinking that parking functions have something to do with this problem? They seem like totally different random processes.

Comment: Ultimately, the five cards in the end when the player loses will be increasingly arranged set of five cards from a random process of parking functions ( if not parking function the game might be end earlier or later).  That was the motivation of using parking fucntion concept

Comment: Parking functions can repeat numbers and don't have to be increasing, e.g. $(3,1,4,1,4)$ while the sequences in your game cannot and do, respectively.